# How to join an Active Directory domain in Lion?

Tags: macos, windows, active-directory

where do I begin in joining an OS X Lion workstation to an existing AD Domain (Server 2008 R2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like it's under System Preferences > Users & Groups > Click on 'Login Options' > then click 'Join' button next to where it says "Network Account Server".

Then the dialog box that comes down allows you to enter the AD domain server there. Click Ok.

[image: Joining an AD Domain on Lion]

Comment: Have you been able to get that to work though? When we try and bind a Lion Mac to Active Directory it takes about 5 minutes and doesn't allow network users to log on properly afterwards.

Comment: Which version of Lion are you on? The latest version 10.7.2, says "Improve Active Directory and LDAP integration." - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4767

Answer (score 0):

There are major problems with the Mac OS Active Directory plug-in that actually started with 10.6.8 and they were NOT fixed in 10.7.2.  I've found that the AD plug-in from Likewise Open to be a very good solution, and it's free.

Kent

Comment: **IMPORTANT: The Likewise PDIS Open Edition 7.0 does not support Mountain Lion.** I lost an entire morning's work reinstalling Mountain Lion after being completely (and utterly), confoundingly locked out of my workstation (password resets, single user mode, nada). That'll teach me to install random, potentially useful third-party plugins.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.  I stopped using Likewise after Apple fixed the AD problem in 10.7.4.

Answer (score 0):

I joined MAC OS X 10.8.3 to AD (windows 2008 R2 SP1) successfully. However faced system hang when accessing 'Security and Privacy' from 'System Preferences'.

In logs saw lot of permission errors. Solved it by 'Repairing Disk Permissions' from Disk Utility.

Comment: The question asks How to join not that you can join, so please expand on "I  joined MAC OS X 10.8.3 to AD (windows 2008 R2 SP1) successfully"